# QueryString always return null after server.UrlDecode

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webpages

My page url is very simple `EmailToFriend.aspx?PID=5&amp;Lang=en-US`

```
    string _pid= Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["PID"]);
    string _lang = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["Lang"]);
```

**result**:

```
_pid=5
_lang= null
```

I am trying to get `QueryString`  value of both `PID` and `Lang` but it return null for lang value while it is present in the url i.e= en-US

While debugging i noticed that it show url as `PID=5&amp%3bLang=en-US`  for following line of code

`string _lang = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["Lang"]);`

I am not sure what is wrong and why it is showing `%3b` in place of `;`

How can i resolve this so that i get the value for QueryString `lang`

If i use only `&` in my url then it works fine with `request["lang"];` problem only happens when i encode url & try to decode it back

article reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

doesn't work for me..

Comment: I don't think you need Server.UrlDecode because Request.QueryString will return a URL decoded value by default.

Answer (score 1):

First, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string): a query string is the part of a (URL) that contains data to be passed to web applications, it is encoded as follows:

> `field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3...`

- The query string is composed of a series of *field-value pairs*.
- Within each pair, the field name and value are separated by an equals sign, `'='`.
- The series of pairs is separated by the ampersand, `'&'`...

Thus, when you have a url as follows:

> `EmailToFriend.aspx?PID=5&amp;Lang=en-US`

You have a querystring with two *field-value pairs*, separated by ampersand (`'&'`):

> `"PID" => "5"`, and `"amp;Lang" => "en-US"`

...

Now, back to your problem:

1. > I am trying to get `QueryString` value of both `PID` and `Lang` but it return null for lang value while it is present in the url i.e= en-US

   The reason why `Lang` always returns null, is because the key does not exist in the qiven URL, instead the key `amp;Lang` exist with the value `en-US`. You can verify this using the following code:

   ```
   string _amplang = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["amp;Lang"]);
   ```
2. > How can i resolve this so that i get the value for QueryString `lang`

   You've basically answered this one yourself. Its by fixing your URL and use the correct form of querystring: `EmailToFriend.aspx?PID=5&Lang=en-US`
3. > article reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
   >   doesn't work for me..

   It does work, but unfortunately you're working it wrong. The URL encoded value of ampersand (`'&'`) is `%26` not `&amp;`. The **HTML encoded** value of ampersand (`'&'`), on the other hand, is `&amp;`. You're probably trying to URL-decode an HTML-encoded value.

   For example, let's say you have the following URL:

   `EmailToFriend.aspx?PID=5&Lang=en-US&Url=EmailToFriend.aspx%3fPID%3d5%26Lang%3den-US`

   If you run the following code:

   ```
   string _pid= Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["PID"]);
   string _lang = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["Lang"]);
   string _url = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["Url"]);
   ```

   You'll have the following value:

   ```
   _pid=5
   _lang= en-US
   _url = EmailToFriend.aspx?PID=5&Lang=en-US
   ```

   The `Url` value is correctly decoded from the query string.